# Excel Locking/Allowing Entry in a Cell Based on its Current Value

Tags: excel

I have Column A where the User picks an asset from the dropdown list.  The asset chosen then determines if all of the cells in the corresponding row are populated with REQ or BLOCK.  This tells the User which cells they need to fill in.  This is working fine and I handle this procedure with the following formula:

=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A5,Sheet1!$A$5:$DB$76,C$1,FALSE )), "", IF(VLOOKUP($A5,Sheet1!$A$5:$DB$76,C$1,FALSE)="x","REQ","BLOCK"))

So every cell will now have REQ or BLOCK in it:

[image]

I want the User to only be able to enter data in the cells with REQ in them, but I am struggling when I enter data validaton for the same cell.  For example, B5 is REQ.  If I go to Data Validation in J16 let's say and enter =B5="REQ" I am allowed to enter in J16, but if I validate in B5 and enter =B5="REQ", I get an error when trying to enter data.  Is it because I'm validating in the same cell that I am referencing?  And, if so, how can I accomplish this?

Here is the partial sheet (Sheet1) with the x's:

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35 | 36 | 37 | 38 | 39 | 40 | 41 | 42 | 43 | 44 | 45 | 46 | 47 | 48 | 49 | 50 | 51 | 52 | 53 | 54 | 55 | 56 | 57 | 58 | 59 | 60 | 61 | 62 | 63 | 64 | 65 | 66 | 67 | 68 | 69 | 70 | 71 | 72 | 73 | 74 | 75 | 76 | 77 | 78 | 79 | 80 | 81 | 82 | 83 | 84 | 85 | 86 | 87 | 88 | 89 | 90 | 91 | 92 | 93 | 94 | 95 | 96 | 97 | 98 | 99 | 100 | 101 | 102 | 103 | 104 | 105 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | General |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Criticality |  |  | Location |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Constructed |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Warranty |  |  |  |  |  |  | Manufactued |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Dimensions |  |  |  |  | Conveyance |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Pump & Motor |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Electrical |  |  |  | HVAC |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | ASSET ID | ASSET NAME/ABBREVIATION ON DRAWING AND SCHEDULE | LINK TO DRWG/DP # | LINK TO SPECIFICATIONS (PDF) | DESCRIPTION | COMMISSIONING (IN-SERVICE) DATE | ORIGINAL COST | EXPECTED USEFUL LIFE (DURATION) | EXPECTED LIFE EXPIRATION DATE | CONTRACTOR/INSTALLING CONTRACTOR/WARRANTY VENDOR | CONTRACTOR'S WEBSITE | CONTRACTOR'S REPRESENTATIVE | CONTRACTOR'S PHONE NUMBER | CONTRACTOR'S E-MAIL | LINK TO PREVENTIVE MAINTENANCE SCHEDULE/ ACTIVITIES | SPARE PARTS LIST | ASSET FAILURE MODES | APPROVED METHODS OF REPAIR | SPECIAL TOOLS LIST | LINK TO O&M MANUALS | PHOTOS | SAFETY | OPERATIONAL | CLIMATE SENSITIVE | LATITUDE/ LONGITUDE COORDINATES | ELEVATION | NORTHING | EASTING | STATE PLAN ELEVATION | STREET ADDRESS | SQUARE FOOTAGE | STATION | ROOM NUMBER | CONSTRUCTION DATE (COMPLETION) | RSMEANS REFERENCE NUMBER | RSMEANS DESCRIPTION | RSMEANS UNIT COST | RSMEANS COST SOURCE PUBLICATION YEAR | PARENT ASSET ID | EXPECTED REHAB CYCLE | EXPECTED REHAB CYCLE METER | CERTIFICATIONS - ASSET/ EQUIPMENT | WARRANTY TYPE | WARRANTY START DATE | WARRANTY EXPIRATION DATE | WARRANTY USAGE EXPIRATION FACTOR | WARRANTY REIMBURSEMENT | LENGTH OF MATERIAL WARRANTY | LENGTH OF LABOR WARRANTY | MANUFACTURE DATE | DELIVERY/INSTALLATION DATE | MANUFACTURER | MODEL | MODEL NUMBER | SERIAL NUMBER | MANUFACTURER'S WEBSITE (LINK) | MANUFACTURER'S REPRESENTATIVE | MANUFACTURER'S REPRESENTATIVE'S PHONE NUMBER | MANUFACTURER'S REPRESENTATIVE'S E-MAIL | SOFTWARE NAME & VERSION # IF APPLICABLE | REQUIRED TRAINING / CERTIFICATION | OEM FAILURE CODES | TYPE | LENGTH | WIDTH | HEIGHT | CAPACITY | WEIGHT | SERVICE LEVEL 1 & 2 | # OF OPENINGS | TRAVEL | MOTOR SIZE | STOPS | SPEED | DOOR TYPE | DOOR MIN OPENING SPEED | DOOR MIN CLOSING SPEED | MEDIA | FLOW RATE | TOTAL HEAD | HORSE POWER | RPM | FIXTURE CONNECTION SITE | FULL LOAD AMPS | MOTOR WATT | VOLTAGE | AMPERAGE | PHASE | HERTZ | ASSOCIATED CONDENSING UNIT | REFRIGERANT | TOTAL COOLING CAPACITY AT 95◦F | SENSIBLE COOLING CAPACITY AT 95◦F | TOTAL COOLING CAPACITY AT 4◦F | COOLING AIR FLOW | HEATING AIR FLOW | AIR FLOW | ENERGY EFFICEINCY RATIO | HEATING CAPACITY AT 5◦F | MCA | MCP | BASIS OF DESIGN | SPACE SERVED | DRIVE TYPE | EXTERNAL STATIC |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Y/N? | Y/N? | Y/N? |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Prorated, Full Value |  |  | e.g., Miles, Cycles, Operating Hours | Parts, Labor, Parts & Labor, Cash, Adjustment, etc. |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ft, in | ft, in | ft, in | GAL, LBS | LBS |  |  | FT-IN |  |  | FPM |  |  |  | Waste Water | (GPM) | (FT) | HP |  | Waste | AMPS |  | V,KV | AMPS |  | HZ |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Station | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | 0 | x | 0 | x | x | x | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! |
| Substructure | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | 0 | x | x | x | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | 0 | 0 | x | x | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! |
| Foundation | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | 0 | x | x | x | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | 0 | 0 | x | x | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! |
| Shell | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | 0 | x | x | x | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | 0 | 0 | x | x | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! |
| Superstructure | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x | 0 | x | x | x | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | 0 | 0 | x | x | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! | #REF! |

Thanks!

Comment: *Is it because I'm validating in the same cell that I am referencing?* Yes. When applying validating rule `=B5="REQ"` in B5 you are setting up that the **only** value allowed in that cell is `REQ` (or null/empty). Any other value will be rejected.

Comment: Yes, but that is exactly what I would want - however it is not working.

Comment: You can protect the sheet and use a subroutine to lock/unlock the cells accordingly to your need.

Comment: Thanks.  Will it work dynamically or will I have to run the subroutine every time the User enters an asset and the cell content changes?

Comment: I mean, you can make it work dynamically. It all depends from what your goal is. You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event: based on the given value in column A your subroutine will unlock the proper cells following the logic you've described in your formula. You will most likely need to also apply the protection during the `Workbook_Open` event in order to apply the protection using the `UserInterfaceOnly` option, so your macro will be able to edit the sheet with no need for the protection to be removed and re-applied.

Comment: By the way: use a @ to signal to someone you are telling/asking them something; otherwise it might not be reported to them. Like: @GreggRosenstein.

Comment: Thanks @Evil Blue Monkey.  I have a base color of red for all cells - when someone enters from the dropdown in Column A some cells throughout the row turn blue - those are the ones I want to allow the User entry to.  But since they started red they are still locked because the macro has run.   Sub lockcellsbycolor()
Dim cl As Range
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
   For Each cl In Range("A5:DB2500")
       If cl.DisplayFormat.Interior.colorIndex = 3 Then
            cl.Locked = True
        Else
            cl.Locked = False
       End If
   Next cl
ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub

Comment: @Evil Blue Monkey there might be a culprit.  Someone picks an asset from Column A and my formula makes it REQ or BLOCK based on the 'x' from Sheet1.  The cells are made blue or red through conditional formatting.  But Excel doesn't seem to recognize the new color.  When I go to a cell that is now red or now blue and look up the RGB color it still shows 128,128,128, which is the original gray color.  Is your code doing nothing because Excel simply thinks all cells are gray when your script is running?  How do we fix?  THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub SubBlock(RangeToCheck As Range, Optional MarkForBlock As String = "BLOCK")
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngCell As Range
    Dim RngLock As Range
    Dim RngUnlock As Range
    
    'Covering each cell in RangeToCheck.
    For Each RngCell In RangeToCheck
        
        'Checking if RngCell contains MarkForBlock.
        If RngCell.Value2 = MarkForBlock Then
            
            'Checking if RngLock hasn't been already set.
            If RngLock Is Nothing Then
                
                'Setting RngLock.
                Set RngLock = RngCell
                
            Else
                
                'Including RngCell in RngLock.
                Set RngLock = Union(RngLock, RngCell)
                
            End If
            
        Else
            
            'Checking if RngUnlock hasn't been already set.
            If RngUnlock Is Nothing Then
                
                'Setting RngUnlock.
                Set RngUnlock = RngCell
                
            Else
                
                'Including RngCell in RngUnlock.
                Set RngUnlock = Union(RngUnlock, RngCell)
                
            End If
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    'Removing protection from the sheet.
    RangeToCheck.Parent.Unprotect
    
    'Checking if RngLock has been set.
    If Not (RngLock Is Nothing) Then
        
        'Locking RngLock.
        RngLock.Locked = True
    
    End If
    
    'Checking if RngUnlock has been set.
    If Not (RngUnlock Is Nothing) Then
        
        'Unlocking RngUnlock.
        RngUnlock.Locked = False
        
    End If
    
    'Applying protection to the sheet.
    RangeToCheck.Parent.Protect
    
End Sub
```

You can call the sourbroutine when needed like this:

```
SubBlock Range("A5:DB2500")
```

Although a range that big would take some time to be covered. You probably want to apply it only to the newly edited rows. Note that you might need to specify the full address of the range (therefore with the name of the sheet) if the activesheet is not the one you want to lock/unlock.

This is a first "easy to implement" solution. More refined ones are totally achievable.

---

## EDIT

Following comments and in order to produce a more refined macro, i've created a subroutine to be put in the sheet's module. Here it is:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngAssetsColumn As Range
    Dim RngIntersection As Range
    Dim RngList As Range
    Dim RngArea As Range
    Dim RngSource As Range
    Dim RngAsset As Range
    Dim RngCell As Range
    Dim RngUnlock As Range
    Dim RngLock As Range
    Dim RngClear As Range
    Dim DblIndex As Double
    Dim DblRow As Double
    Dim DblColumn As Double
    Dim StrRequestedDataMarker As String
    Dim VarEvaluation() As Variant
    Dim VarScenarios(1 To 3, 1 To 3) As Variant
    
    'SETTINGS:
    
    'Range with the list to be locked/unlocked (assets column not included).
    Set RngList = Me.Range("B5:DB2500")
    
    'Column with the assets.
    Set RngAssetsColumn = Me.Range("A5:A2500")
    
    'Range with the list that specify what data are need for the given asset.
    Set RngSource = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:DB76")
    
    'Mark used in the RngSource to signal the requested data.
    StrRequestedDataMarker = "x"
    
    'Range that will be unlocked. Set equal to RngAssetsColumn so it can be put into VarScenarios with no error while using a range that won't be locked/unlocked anyway.
    Set RngUnlock = RngAssetsColumn
    
    'Range that will be locked. Set equal to RngAssetsColumn so it can be put into VarScenarios with no error while using a range that won't be locked/unlocked anyway.
    Set RngLock = RngAssetsColumn
    
    'Range that will be locked and clear. Set equal to RngAssetsColumn so it can be put into VarScenarios with no error while using a range that won't be locked/unlocked anyway.
    Set RngClear = RngAssetsColumn
    
    'Array with all the possible scenarios: _
    -row 1 is for unlocked cells, row 2 for locked cells, row 3 for cleared cells _
    -column 1 is for the cell value, column 2 is for the actual range, column 3 is for the interior color _
    -set cell value as Empty returns an empty cell _
    -set interior color as Empty return a cell with no color
    VarScenarios(1, 1) = "REQ"
    Set VarScenarios(1, 2) = RngUnlock
    VarScenarios(1, 3) = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    
    VarScenarios(2, 1) = "BLOCK"
    Set VarScenarios(2, 2) = RngLock
    VarScenarios(2, 3) = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    
    VarScenarios(3, 1) = Empty
    Set VarScenarios(3, 2) = RngClear
    VarScenarios(3, 3) = Empty
    
    'Setting RngIntersection as the intersection between RngAssetsColumn and Target (the range edited).
    Set RngIntersection = Intersect(RngAssetsColumn, Target)
    
    'Checking if RngIntersection is nothing (no edit made to RngAssetsColumn).
    If RngIntersection Is Nothing Then
        
        'No intersection needs no further actions.
        
    Else
        
        'Removing protection from the sheet.
        RngList.Parent.Unprotect
        
        'Setting RngIntersection to cover the rows in RngList that will be locked/unlocked.
        Set RngIntersection = Intersect(RngIntersection.EntireRow, RngList)
        
        'Covering each area in RngIntersection.
        For Each RngArea In RngIntersection.Areas
            
            'Redeclaring VarEvaluation to host the values that will be reported in RngArea.
            ReDim VarEvaluation(1 To RngArea.Rows.Count, 1 To RngArea.Columns.Count)
            
            'Covering each cell in RngArea.
            For Each RngCell In RngArea
                
                'Setting RngAsset as the cell with the asset for the given row.
                Set RngAsset = RngAssetsColumn.Parent.Cells(RngCell.Row, RngAssetsColumn.Column)
                
                'Setting DblRow to identify the reference of RngCell within RngArea.
                DblRow = RngCell.Row - RngArea.Row + 1
                
                'Setting DblColumn to identify the reference of RngCell within RngArea.
                DblColumn = RngCell.Column - RngArea.Column + 1
                
                'Focusing the excel functions library.
                With Excel.WorksheetFunction
                    
                    'Checking if the given asset is enlisted in RngSource while the asset name has a lenght greater than zero.
                    If .CountIf(RngSource, RngAsset.Value2) > 0 And Len(RngAsset.Value2) > 0 Then Then
                        
                        'Checking if the given data for the given asset is requested as specified in RngSource by StrRequestedDataMarker.
                        If .VLookup(RngAsset.Value2, RngSource, DblColumn + 1, False) = StrRequestedDataMarker Then
                            
                            'Setting DblIndex to the row in VarScenarios for the unlock scenario.
                            DblIndex = 1
                            
                        Else
                            
                            'Setting DblIndex to the row in VarScenarios for the lock scenario.
                            DblIndex = 2
                            
                        End If
                        
                    Else
                        
                        'Setting DblIndex to the row in VarScenarios for the clear scenario.
                        DblIndex = 3
                        
                    End If
                    
                End With
                
                'Checking if the proper range hasn't been already set (same address as the fake range).
                If VarScenarios(DblIndex, 2).Address = RngAssetsColumn.Address Then
                    
                    'Setting the proper range.
                    Set VarScenarios(DblIndex, 2) = RngCell
                    
                Else
                    
                    'Including RngCell in the proper range.
                    Set VarScenarios(DblIndex, 2) = Union(VarScenarios(DblIndex, 2), RngCell)
                    
                End If
                
                'Reporting the proper value in VarEvaluation.
                VarEvaluation(DblRow, DblColumn) = VarScenarios(DblIndex, 1)
                
            Next
            
            'Reporting VarEvaluation in RngArea.
            RngArea.Value2 = VarEvaluation
            
        Next
        
        'Covering each scenario.
        For DblIndex = 1 To UBound(VarScenarios)
            
            'Checking if the proper range hasn't been already set (same address as the fake range).
            If VarScenarios(DblIndex, 2).Address = RngAssetsColumn.Address Then
                
                'No range need no further actions.
                
            Else
                
                'Checking if no color is requested.
                If VarScenarios(DblIndex, 3) = Empty Then
                    
                    'Setting the proper range with the standard color.
                    VarScenarios(DblIndex, 2).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                    
                Else
                    
                    'Setting the proper range with the proper color.
                    VarScenarios(DblIndex, 2).Interior.Color = VarScenarios(DblIndex, 3)
                
                End If
                
                'Locking/Unlocking the proper range (only the unlock range needs to be unlocked).
                VarScenarios(DblIndex, 2).Locked = (DblIndex <> 1)
                
            End If
            
        Next
        
        'Applying protection to the sheet.
        RngList.Parent.Protect
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

It will activate anytime the user will modify the specified range (`RngAssetsColumn`). You can tune it accordingly to your need, changing ranges, colors, mark-words.

Comment: Thanks @Evil Blue Monkey.  Where do I call the subroutine?  What am I missing because I don't see any results when implementing the code?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Evil Blue Monkey can I send you my source file?

Comment: Better not. To be clear: the user is supposed to specify an asset in column A then the formula you posted is to be applied to the row and based on that formula cells have to be locked accordingly; is that the case?

Comment: Correct @ Evil Blue Monkey.  We start out with all cells locked outside of Column A.  Then when someone picks from the Column A dropdown my formula makes all the columns in that row either Blue with the word REQ in it or Red with the word BLOCK in it.  At this point all of Column A remains unlocked and all cells that are Blue with REQ in them are now unlocked.

Comment: New more advanced macro added. This one is to be placed in the sheet's module. Once placed, it will automatically determine if an asset has been specified. In such case (accordingly to the specifications in Sheet1) it will edit the list locking/unlocking the cells, filling them with the specified colors and the specified values.

Comment: Thanks @Evil Blue Monkey - you are always so helpful.  I have one request and one concern.  The request is for the RngList to all start locked.  We know once we get the REQ or BLOCK what to do, but a User shouldn't be able to enter anything in a cell that starts blank that's not in Column A.  Also, once a User enters something in a REQ cell they should be able to enter and re-enter in that cell (which they can).  My concern is that the script isn't working properly - it's not stopping me from entering in the BLOCK cells.  Thoughts?

Comment: I am sharing the file here:  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1D6tS-DXFsAHjoEfjWTPzO1jvJPvpP9C7?usp=drive_link

Comment: The RngList should start as all locked by default. Unless you've changed it manually, cells are set as locked as a standard. Anyway you can select the range and manually set it as locked. The macro is set to have any cell locked but those with a known asset specified with a REQ data. The macro is also set to reapply the protection to the sheet. I see no reason why it shouldn't be working as planned. Is it reporting the REQ and BLOCK correctly with the proper colors?

Comment: it is reporting the REQ and BLOCK correctly with the proper colors.  I shared the file in my previous comment.  It's as if there is no locking at all.  The sheet is protected but I can enter in boxes before REQ and BLOCK are populated and I can enter in all cells even when it says BLOCK

Comment: The link you granted said i will recive a mail to inform me if i can access the file. Try one thing: start recoding a macro, unprotect a cell and then protect it again. Post the code. It should be good for nothing, but i have no good hypotesis.

Comment: OK I will.  I'm so desperate to get done by Sunday night I'll try anything I can email file as well

Comment: Sub Protect()
'
' Protect Macro
'

'
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
End Sub

Comment: #Evil Blue Monkey just an update.  If I manually lock all cells B5:DB2500 and then enter something in Column A, ALL cells B5:DB2500 remain locked and I can't enter - even those with REQ.  If I manually unlock all cells B5:DB2500 and then enter something in Column A, ALL cells B5:DB2500 remain unlocked and I can enter anything anywhere - even the cells with 'BLOCK'.  The code has no effect on any cell.  HELP - thanks!

Comment: #Evil Blue Monkey it's also not recognizing REQ or BLOCK as an entry.  If I used this as the only macro it's treating cells with REQ and BLOCK as empty and letting me enter data.  But once I enter something in the cell it is now locked.....................Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim c As Range
Set c = Range("B5:DB2500")
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
For Each c In Target
    If c.Value = "" Then
        c.Locked = False
    Else
        c.Locked = True
    End If
Next c
ActiveSheet.Protect
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Comment: Did you copied the second code (the one after the big "EDIT" title) i've granted in the module of the sheet hosting the list? That code doesn't need any extra code to work, nor conditional formatting, nor formulas. It change the values, the colors and the lock status of the ranges on its own. You can try by creating a new file with 2 sheets. One sheet will be called Sheet1 and (just like your Sheet1) will host the list of known assets with all the **x**es to specify which data are needed. The second one (lets call it Sheet2) will host the list of the assets specified by the user. [...]

Comment: [...] Insert a few assets in the range A5:DB76 of Sheet1, copy my second code in the sheet module of Sheet2 and then try to type an asset name in range A5 of Sheet2. That's all you need to make it work.

Comment: #Evil Blue Monkey still no effect thanks and a 1004 error - If .VLookup(RngAsset.Value2, RngSource, DblColumn, False) = StrRequestedDataMarker Then

Comment: #Evil Blue Monkey you gave up on me?

Comment: The 1004 error while unexpected is probably due to DblColumn exceeding RngSource. Basically the function is searching beyond the limit of RngSource. No idea why it would do that. Try again and if it occurs check the values of `RngAsset.Value2`, `RngSource.Address` and `DblColumn`. You can do it via the immediate window like explained [here](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/debug-print-immediate-window). Report then their values.

Comment: Hi @Evil Blue Monkey these were the results of the immediate window queries:  ?RngAsset.Value2
Station
?RngSource.Address
$A$5:$DB$76
?DblColumn
 79

Comment: Well, there goes my hypotesis. At least i've found another bug in that line of code. It should be `If .VLookup(RngAsset.Value2, RngSource, DblColumn + 1, False) = StrRequestedDataMarker Then`. I've edited the code. It's probably not the reason of the error though. Since i'm still wandering in the dark let's try this: using [this](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) post the data of your two sheets (any personal or sensible information should be replaced by fake equivalent ones before posting). What are their names? Sheet1 for the known assets.

Comment: I was able to generate a table with your utility - how do I 'send' it to you?

Comment: You can edit your original question and add it.

Comment: I get an error saying that I am exceeding the number of characters (table is 188,000)

Comment: Try a section of the sheets.

Comment: done.  That is Sheet1.  Sheet2 is blank except for a dropdown box in Column A from 5 to 2500 that has all of the Assets in them (the first column of data in Sheet 1 that I just pasted in the original question).  Thanks!

Comment: The good news is that the error occurred to me too finally and i've edited the code to avoid it. Still not sure why it happened though. It was caused when the VLOOKUP function was looking for a some kind of empty string. What's strange is that it didn't happend during my tests. Don't know why "your" empty string should have been different. I'll take one more look at the problem. Anyway: code edited. Test it and send feedbacks.

Comment: Thanks @Evil Blue Monkey.  I'm getting another 1004 error - on the code that you said where the problem is even with the updated code....If .VLookup(RngAsset.Value2, RngSource, DblColumn + 1, False) = StrRequestedDataMarker Then

Comment: Ok, the problem is most likely generated by all those #REF! errors you have in your data. Get rid of them and it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Evil Blue Monkey.  While a separate file did have formulas that prompted #REF! errors in the cell I have done a copy - paste values to what is now Sheet1.  So even though you see #REF! they are all just text entries.  Shouldn't your script work for them since we're only looking whether or not the value is an 'x' or not?

Comment: Point is: VLOOKUP will evaluate that range and most likely interpret those text as errors which will make it return an error. At least that's what i suppose it will do and that would cause the error. If you can't get rid of them i will have to edit the code.

Comment: I did a Find-Replace and replaced all the #REF! text with blank and everything seems to be working great!  The one issue I have is that if I pick the asset from the dropdown box in Column A the script runs and I can enter in the Blue REQ cells and can't enter in the Red BLOCK cells, which is perfect.  But when I go to the next row to enter another asset the sheet is protected and I can't choose an asset.

Comment: I can do it by manually unlocking the cells in Column A or just calling them to be unlocked in the VBA script - all should be good!  Thank you so much for your patience and work on this one, and your continued help in general.  I am learning and hope to be less and less dependent as we move along.  I'll shout if I need anything - THANK YOU!

Comment: many thanks again.  One last question.  We have the blue cells that are unlocked for entry and the red cells that are locked.  I've added the functionality (through conditional formatting) that if the User enters data into a blue cell it turns green upon entry indicating the task is completed.  I want it to return to blue if the User then deletes the contents.  I don't want to lock the cell after entry in case the User made a mistake and needs to change the value.  I'm sure this isn't difficult but I can't figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: You can use a series of formula based conditional format. Selecting the range B5:DB2500 (with cell B5 active) apply a green conditional format with formula `=B5<>""`, a blue conditional format with formula `=B5="REQ"`, a red conditional format with formula `=B5="BLOCK"`. Mind that the order of application is also important and if the cells turn out all green you probably need to sort properly the list of conditional formats. Know that the conditional formatting will make the coloring part of the macro superfluous therefore you should probably change the code accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your help on this.  Now instead of the assets being in Column A I have five columns of assets.  Some are three deep, some are four deep, and some are five deep.  How do I trigger the script based on the level of asset?  So sometimes I want to trigger it once the user has filled in the third column but sometimes the fourth and sometimes the fifth.  Thanks!

Comment: I guess quick-fix might be creating an extra column that specify the asset you are picking in the columns and use that as the asset reference column. It might need some extra tweaking. You might want to create another question if you have encountered another problem. This one has expired and the number of comments is way higher than the normally accepted.

Comment: check this out...and thanks!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77348660/vba-macro-row-data-not-preserved-when-previous-row-is-deleted